# HighCharts navigator to keep range after async data load. (LazyLoad)

Tags: javascript, highcharts, lazy-loading

I am doing something similar to the HighCharts Lazy Loader example. It works, except that when I zoom into a region, I fetch higher resolution data and update via

```
chart.series[1].setData(data);
```

This resets the navigator range (extremes?) to the range of new incoming data. I am using almost everything that the lazy load example talks about, but no use.

```
navigator:{adaptToUpdatedData:false},
scrollbar:{liveRedraw:false}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo ?

Comment: The backend api returning async data is not public.

Comment: Can't you just set the range again after you load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the only way to do this is to make the new data array match to the required range with empty values.

```
http://forums.highcharts.com/highstock-usage/any-way-to-force-x-axis-extremes-to-match-selected-timeframe-t31154/
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use:

```
chart.series[1].setData(data);
```

I'm pretty sure there should be:

```
chart.series[0].setData(data);
```

Simply, if you have just one series on a chart, then `series[0]` -> your series, and `series[1]` is series in navigator. That's most probably reason why you get navigator updated, but you want to update series.

Comment: no, i have multiple series. that is not an issue. no matter which series I update, navigator extremes will always try to match the maximum xaxis length

Comment: How do you add your series? Using `addSeries()` or when initializing chart? Anyway, as you have comment above, without live demo we can only guess what is wrong. Just make sure you didn't make any mistakes, when using [this](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading) example.

Answer (score 1):

Try using setExtreme function in the callback of the lazyload. http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.setExtremes

Comment: i have a callback at afterSetExtremes, but how to SET the new extremes. This is a callback, not a method to set extremes.